# Straightedge and compass theory in three dimensions

Tags: reference-request, geometric-construction

I'm looking for a reference on the theory of straightedge and compass constructions in three dimensions akin to Euclid's *Elements* in two dimensions. More specifically, I mean a theory of geometric constructions where one is allowed lines between any two points, planes through any three non-colinear points, and spheres with a given center and radius. My preliminary Google searches aren't giving anything but surely this has been studied.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://thenullhypodermic.blogspot.com/2012/01/three-dimensional-constructions.html ? (Not a lot of results there, however; I thought there was more but I'm not finding it right now.)

Comment: @DavidK, Yes, this is the same idea, but I was hoping for a reference to literature on the subject if any exists.

Comment: See [Solid Geometry](https://books.google.com/books?id=-TQZAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover) by Hawkes, Luby, and Touton (1922 edition available as free e-book), which articulates a slightly different (but equivalent) approach on pg. 314 (Sec. 397 Constructions).

Comment: There is also an extensive list of constructions in Euclid's Elements; see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Construction_of_Regular_Dodecahedron_within_Given_Sphere for example. I think Euclid (like Hawkes, Luby, and Touton) constructed circles in planes rather than spheres in space, but I believe the constructable objects are the same either way.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first chapters of *Elementary Geometry* by John Roe could be useful. According to the *Preface* the first and the third chapter use a "classical approach, starting from fundamental properties of parallelism, measurement, and so on", whereas the rest of the book uses the "algebraic approach", i.e. analytic geometry. At the end there is also a list of references.