# Can platonic solids be constructed using compass and straightedge?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction, platonic-solids

By moving the concept of geometric construction into three dimensions, could one trace the 3D wireframe of any of the five platonic solids using only a compass and straightedge?

If not, what additional tools would be required?

I imagine the construction taking place in a "void" of sorts, without the luxury of a preexisting plane. No one $xy$, $xz$ or $yz$ plane is visualized.

**Rules copied from [TheNullHypodermic](http://thenullhypodermic.blogspot.se/2012/01/three-dimensional-constructions.html?m=1):**

Draw a line between any two distinct points.

Draw a circle with one point as the center, and any other point on its circumference.

Draw an arbitrary point on a line or a circle, or off it.

Draw the point at the intersection of two lines (if they intersect).

Draw the point (or two) at the intersection of two circles (if they intersect).

Draw the point (or two) at the intersection of a line and a circle (if they intersect).

Comment: Some would argue, that not only that this can be done, but that in *The Elements* Euclid actually did so.

Comment: In 2D constructions, I can select an arbitrary point and swing a circle around it.  If I have a known radius I can make that circle match in size.  What are the equivalents in your 3D universe?  Please make the question clear.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry, you say you can make the circle match in size. I do not understand what the circle is "matching" in size.

Comment: This might interest you: http://thenullhypodermic.blogspot.com/2012/01/three-dimensional-constructions.html

Comment: @Ola By "matching in size", he means that if you have a segment of some desired length, and a center point then you can make a circle with that center point and a radius that "matches the length" of that segment.

Comment: The rule for circles does not work in 3D.  Given a center and another point, there is a whole sphere that matches.  That is why I asked how the compass works in 3D.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see. Thanks.

Comment: There's also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073940. Perhaps that older question (which never got an answer) should be marked as a duplicate of this newer one.

Comment: OP: You've copied from my article, which I don't have a problem with, but you've copied only the rules for two dimensions.  There is a set of rules for three dimensions further down that article.  See here: http://thenullhypodermic.blogspot.com/2012/01/three-dimensional-constructions.html

Comment: @DavidK offered some comments on my blog post back at The Null Hypodermic that somehow got deleted.  I found an archive of them, but have no idea how to restore them.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define how you use the compass and straightedge to define points that are not in the original plane.  You can construct segments of the proper lengths to have the coordinates of the corners of the Platonic solids.  How you translate those coordinates into a point in 3D is not clear to me.  How do you get the $z$ axis given the $xy$ plane?

Arthur suggested we consider the compass to make spheres and the straightedge to be able to make planes.  To construct the regular tetrahedron then you just construct an equilateral triangle in the plane and swing spheres from each corner with radius equal to the side of the triangle.  The point where the three spheres intersect is the top point.  Constructing a cube is easy as well.  Construct a square, then swing spheres of size $\sqrt 2$ times the side from to diagonally opposite corners plus one of side $\sqrt 3$ times the side from the other two.  The intersections get two of the top corners of the cube.  The others can also be done because the corners are all at points that can be expressed with addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and square roots.

Comment: If this is meant as an answer, and not a comment, perhaps you could at the very least suggest some way to solve the problems you raise. Such as "if your compass draws spheres instead of circles, then yes, you can construct the Platonic solids"

Comment: @Arthur:  that is a good way of translating compasses and straightedges into 3D that I hadn't thought about.  I will suggest constructions using them.

Comment: I imagine the construction taking place in a "void" of sorts. No one $xy$, $xz$ or $yz$ plane can be isolated.The best analogy i have is tracing one-dimensional curves in thin air with a 3D-pen.

Comment: Another possibility is to do your geometric construction on the plane (regarded as a sheet of paper), and then fold it to get your 3D shape.

Comment: @Ola:  You need to define what the compass and straightedge can do, then.